# Notion of top-level and low-level const

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

We can define any object to be a low-level `const` by putting the `const` before the base type. If a top-level `const` is defined by placing `const` after an objects declarator. So this immediately makes sense for pointers since something like `int *const p = i` defines `p` be a `const` pointer to an `int`. This distinction is clear. However I am wondering if such a distinction can be made for references. I have already tried to compile something as follows,

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 40;
    int &const r = i;
}
```

which returns a compile time error. However it got me thinking why? If the purpose of low-level `const` is to ensure the address being pointed to cannot be changed then why is this not possible for a reference to be a low-level `const` since it by definition cannot be bound to a different object after initialisation. Should we not consider all references by default as low-level `const`? If not, why?

Comment: A reference cannot be changed after it is initialized, so the `const` in `int &const r = i;` is redundant. MSVC doesn't produce an error, but a warning: "warning C4227: anachronism used: qualifiers on reference are ignored".

Comment: @wohlstad Apparently, according to Microsoft, it is an [outdated practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4227?view=msvc-170).

Comment: Your vernacular isn't doing you any favors here. Google the clockwise spiral rule, remembering that, when it comes to C++, you can throw out half of it as redundant when entering reference-realms as opposed to pointers, as references are already immutable post-initialization. IMHO, the only confusing part about this is why some toolchains hard-error this (ex: clang) which I believe correct, while others do not (MSVC). I have *not* tried it, but I suspect if you turned off language extensions and enforced pedantic standard compliance, the latter would puke similar to the former.